# The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

Tags: java

I am new to coding, but I found that when I take this line of code out of `notepad++` the error no longer exists

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 0);
```

any ideas?

Comment: You have method call on the left of the assignment. This is a violation of Java syntax.

Comment: Does `GetComponent` take a parameter of `Vector2`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It seems the op needs to post up more info in order to be sure what exactly is going on ?

Comment: Probably trying to set a public field of GetComponent(). velocity is public, so there may be others. Not very Java-ish.

Comment: @KickButtowski It's reasonable obvious, you can't "assign" a value to a method, but can you pass a `Vector2` to `GetComponent` or do they just want the result as a variable...

Answer (score 0):

This is an assignment statement `= new Vector2(GetComponent().velocity.x, 0);` and in assign statement you should assign value to some variable or property of some class but you are trying to assign value to function which is wrong. it should be like this

```
  Vector2 vect = new Vector2(GetComponent().velocity.x, 0);
```